# Firebase Analytics console "Latest Release" shows "No data to display"

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

Firebase Analytics console "Latest Release" suddenly shows "No data to display".

I use this feature to understand how much % of users has been updated to the latest version. It was showing data until a day before yesterday. Suddenly it started showing "No data to display". Is this something related to settings? For example, I could see the Dashboard. I couldn't get much help in any of the forums.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not alone. I have the same problem on 4 out of 5 projects. Most have a "No data to display" notification, while one has a " Report is updated periodically throughout the day"
I sent a GET request to the host that firebase is knocking on and got a 404 error

```
{
  “error”: {
    “code”: 404,
    “message”: “Requested entity was not found.“,
    “status”: “NOT_FOUND”
  }
}
```

So I think the problem is with the Firebase servers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was the issue on the Firebase server side. Without doing anything on our side, it started working again. For those who still has problem, try contacting Firebase.